# Adding text formatting tool bar like one on in mail compose in hotmail or gmail?

Tags: asp.net, android-layout, web

I am developing a note taking application on android, where i need to add the text editing tool bar like on in gmail or hotmail's compose mail option. Like formatting Bold or Italic your note. is there any plug in sort of tool bar that i can use? because I want develop have a website(in asp.net)for the same application as well? how can i add that?

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never! For your website you sure can use some of the jquery plugins. Most popular I believe are the MarkItUp! and jwysiwyg. Just search for "jQuery Text Editor Plugins" in the web.